# IMP-00019: row rejected due to ORACLE error 1

Tags: oracle, constraints, oracle-dump

I'm working on import data to oracle.

I create a new user thelinh and new database blogi in oracle. Currently, there is no data in the database blogi.

Then run the below command:

> IMP thelinh/Thelinh05@blogi FILE= D:\source\rabbit\db_dmp\billuser.dmp
> FULL=Y IGNORE=Y log=log.txt

The log show many error like below:

> IMP-00019: row rejected due to ORACLE error 1 IMP-00003: ORACLE error
> 1 encountered ORA-00001: unique constraint
> (SYSTEM.REPCAT$_AUDIT_ATTRIBUTE_PK) violated.

Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to import the row that already exists in the database. Are you sure you need to import SYSTEM schema? I think it is better to import only schemas that you need and drop/clear them before the import. Did this import complete? If so I believe you can ignore this error.

You can also use the [ignore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL1719) parameter.

Also, if you can use the datapump (`expdp`/`impdp`) to export/imprt this has TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION, that lets you specify the action to take if imported object already exists (APPEND, REPLACE, SKIP and TRUNCATE).